# Where do I buy power specific outfit?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I pledged to [Felicia Winters](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Felicia_Winters) Power and currently I got rank 4. It should give me access to [Pulse Disruptor](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Pulse_Disruptor) but I checked a few controlled systems and couldn't find it on sale. Where do I need to look for it?

Comment: Have you been pledged to Winters for over 4 weeks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power specific equipment requires that you be levelled up with that power and that you have been allied to them for at least 4 weeks.

Once you have the power specific variants should be sold at stations that stock the regular variants (weirdly, even if they are in a hostile system).